# how to add new filed to opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to add three more filed to cart page .()

```
<input name="pr_name">
<input name="pr_phone >
<input name="pr_add">
```

can any one help me to add these files to cart .

Comment: can you share screenshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to modify the following:

the model for the cart /catalog/model/checkout
the controller for the cart /catalog/controller/checkout
the view for the cart whatever theme you are using

finally you will need to do the same for the admin panel and depending on where you would like to see them for example you might want to view them in the invoice you will need to change the model / controller that correspond to that. unfortunately its not like a plug and play thing.

Comment: how they are passing quantity ?

Comment: quantity is passed through sessions plus it is a predefined field in the database. however i think what you are looking for is product  options maybe? on the product level you can add custom fields called options and they can be of multiple types such as text, select etc.